# Clarification on how virtual memory manager in Windows fetches memory mapped file data

Tags: c, winapi, window

Say, if I have a large file that I map into the virtual address space of my process as such:

```
//Error handling is omitted for brevity
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"path-to\\file", 
            GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
HANDLE hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
char* pAddress = (char*)MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping,
            FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

//And get the data
char data_byte = pAddress[offset];

//Then remember to do the cleanup ....
```

When does the kernel virtual memory manager read the actual data from the file on disk (or performs the I/O operation to fetch the data from the hard drive):

A) When `MapViewOfFile` is called, or

B) When I access it with `pAddress[offset]`?

And a second question if the answer above is B -- when it fetches the data:

C) Does it read the entire file, or

D) Only the encompassing page (4K size, or so)?

Comment: answer - B and D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**B** and **D**

when you call `MapViewOfFile` (`ZwMapViewOfSection`) kernel reserve range of virtual for view but not associate it with real physical pages (so not allocate physical pages at begin). when you first time access some address inside section view - because it yet not associated with physical page (PTE not valid ) - exception will be generated by cpu. while system handle this exception, it allocate already physical page, associate virtual address with this page, read data from file to it (if section backed by file) and continue execution from the instruction, which generate exception.

so system not just read data from file, when you map it in memory, but wait until your first access it. and on first access - it read data not entire section range (section can begin not from file begin and end not at file end) but only accessed page (may be several pages)

Comment: The `ETHREAD` structure has a couple of values that potentially affect how many pages get read in as a cluster when handling a page fault: `DisablePageFaultClustering` (default is false) and `ReadClusterSize` (default is 7). It appears to work as expected. I lowered `ReadClusterSize` to 3 for a thread and had it access a mapped data file. In a local kernel debugger I could see that after loading two sequential pages, the next `ReadClusterSize - 1`  pages were already valid.